# Call a function with parameter in Jquery ( on click )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to call the function sendData when i click on the button X 
i'm having a problem with "" and '' don t know how to call the function properly

any help

```
var txt1 = $(this).val() ;  
var txt2 = $('<button type="button" id="'+txt1+'" class="myButton"> '+txt1+' <button type="button" onclick='sendData(txt1)'>X</button> </button>');

$("p").append(txt2);   // Append new elements
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use inline JS. You can simply check for the click event bubbling up from `.myButton` instead. If you still want to use inline JS, this should work: `onclick="sendData(' + txt1 + ')"`

Comment: You've used single quotes around `sendData(txt1)` which means it is outside the string. You probably wanted to use double quotes so the code is part of the string.

Comment: onclick="sendData('+ txt1 +')"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *htmlString* you are generating is not properly formatted. Try the following:

```js
var txt1 = 'test';  
var txt2 = $('<button type="button" id="'+txt1+'" class="myButton"> '+txt1+' <button type="button" onclick=sendData("'+txt1+'")>X</button> </button>');

$("p").append(txt2);

function sendData(data){
  alert(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Though I prefer using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
var txt1 = 'test' ;  
var txt2 = $(`<button type="button" id="${txt1}" class="myButton"> ${txt1} <button type="button" onclick='sendData("${txt1}")'>X</button> </button>`);

$('p').append(txt2);

function sendData(data){
  alert(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a single quote around your sendData function -

Yours -

`var txt2 = $('<button type="button" id="' + txt1 + '" class="myButton"> ' + txt1 + ' <button type="button" onclick='sendData(txt1)'>X</button> </button>');`

Correct -

`var txt2 = $('<button type="button" id="' + txt1 + '" class="myButton"> ' + txt1 + ' <button type="button" onClick='+sendData(txt1)+'>X</button></button > ');`

FYI - To avoid single or double quote problem you can use ES6 feature of template literals -

```
var txt2 = $(`<button type="button" id="${txt1}" class="myButton">${txt1}<button type="button" onclick=${sendData(txt1)}>X</button> </button>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use the return value of creating the button, and add an eventhandler to it, to use that to forward your data to the `sendData` function

```js
const inputField = $('<input type="text" />');
const button = $('<button type="button">Submit</button>');
$(button).on('click', function() {
  sendData( inputField.val() );
});

function sendData( data ) {
  console.log( data );
}

$('#container').append( inputField ).append( button );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
```

```js
var txt1 = "a";  
      var txt2 = $('<button type="button" id='+txt1+' class="myButton"> '+txt1+' <button type="button" onclick='+sendData(txt1)+'>X</button> </button>');
   $("p").append(txt2);   // Append new elements  
   
   function sendData(x)
   {
   console.log(x)
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use click event handler like below:

```
$(document).on("click", "#idOfButtonThatYouClicked" function() {
    //do stuffs or call other functions
    //var value = $("#someOtherPlace").value();
    //sendData(value);
});
```

More here: http://api.jquery.com/on/